# How do you type Encircled Kanji? (丸囲み文字)

Tags: discussion, kanji

I am needing to use a lot of encircled kanji. (See [Usage of Encircled Kanji](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/50511/usage-of-encircled-kanji))

However, I am using Linux, and I cannot find any information on how to actually *type* the encircled kanji on Linux. Copying and pasting the characters is not viable long-term.

Does anyone know how to type 丸囲み文字 characters on Linux?

Comment: I don't know if there is an easy way. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 and am able to input Unicode characters directly by using Ctrl+Shift+U, then type the code, followed by ENTER or SHIFT. So, ㊚ is Ctrl+Shift+U, then 329A, then ENTER or SHIFT. But if you've looked up the Unicode for ㊚ you could just cut and paste. You can register regularly used characters in the dictionary tool. So I registered otoko to get ㊚. There are only a few dozen that you are likely to use, so the dictionary tool might be the best option

Comment: FYI I never installed mozc myself, but on Japanese input method type- １-then-convert should work. https://qiita.com/ryupim/items/3eead424b75240331c04

Comment: I created a very simple user dictionary that you can import to the MOZC dictionary tool
https://1drv.ms/t/s!AnjIzJUqvK39h9ksXYGqssGBIHVVlg?e=OItFl8

Comment: The closest that I've found so far is to type まる+<number or katakana>, then convert to the circled form, but this only works for numbers & katakana. For circled or square kanji or alphabet characters, I haven't been able to find a robust way of doing it. @UsoDayo Thanks for the info on typing unicode on Linux. Thanks also for the dictionary tip; it is a good second best to having a native way of typing the characters.

Comment: @Elessar まる＋ is good. It seems to work for some kanji too. まるひ --> ㊙ まるかん --> ㊬ Maybe it's just a matter of knowing what reading of the kanji to use. Edit: I think this is the answer.